# NHibernate transaction commit, what will be committed to database?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, transactions

I have following code:

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
  var entity = session.Get<Entity>(id);
  entity.Property1 = "new value";
  using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
  {
    entity.Property2 = "new value";
    tx.Commit();
  }
}
```

And now, I am confused, when `tx.Commit()`, what will be committed to database?
Is only the `Property2` (in transaction scope part) will be committed, or both `Property1` and `Property2` will be committed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any changes you make to a persistent object will be sent to the database when the session is flushed, and committing a transaction will flush the session. Note that the session may be flushed automatically in some cases, such as when working with database generated identifiers or when issuing a query.

It is confusing that in NHibernate you can have transaction blocks that contain just a commit. For readability, I would rewrite this as:

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
  using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
  {
      var entity = session.Get<Entity>(id);
      entity.Property1 = "new value";
      entity.Property2 = "new value";
      tx.Commit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks your patiently answer, I still have a problem. What is the difference between `ISession.Flush()` and `ITransaction.Commit()` ? Both of them can synchronize the data to database, but using the `ITransaction` have to begin it before commiting, and the `ISession.BeginTransaction()` is a confusing operation, because every changes of session will be committed but not the changes in the transaction scope (from `BeginTransaction()` to `Commit()`).

Comment: It's explained well in the documentation: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata. My recommendation is to set the session's FlushMode to Commit and use transactions.

Answer (score 0):

All properties from entity will be committed. In your configuration you can set a setting that outputs the sql to the console, you can see what queries it sends on every commit.

Comment: Oooo, so, it is commit the changes from the session open not the trasaction begin ?